# How to encode? response.cookie with asp classic - vbscript?

Tags: cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

Im trying to set a cookie with the value /sv/en and the / ends up like %2F in the cookie, so I wonder how to encode or whatever you have to do to write a / instead.

Im using this to set the cookie now.

```
 Response.Cookies("googtrans")="/sv/en"
 Response.Cookies("googtrans").path = "/"
 Response.Cookies("googtrans").expires = "2038-01-01 10:00"
 Response.Cookies("googtrans").domain = ".mypage.se"
```

So how can I write a / in the cookie? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the Response.Cookies collection URL Encoding (and vice versa URL Decoding) is implicit.

To prevent this, you need to set a raw cookie with [Response.AddHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327(v=vs.90).aspx) instead.

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "googtrans=/sv/en; expires=2038-01-01 10:00; domain=.mypage.se; path=/"
```

Comment: Thanks, Kul-Tigin. It works! But how do I set if I want the domain to be www.mypage.se as well as .mypage.se? If I use Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "googtrans=/sv/en; expires=2038-01-01 10:00; domain=www.mypage.se; path=/" then it becomes .www.mypage.se and not www.mypage.se - see the dot before www. Thanks.

Comment: I simply want to set that the google cookie "googtrans" never expires, with add header or javascript somehow, and this is almost right :-)

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson `.mypage.se` will work all the subdomains of `mypage.se` including domain name itself too.

Comment: Ok, but when I use google translate on my page it set 2 cookies, one with mypage.se and one with www.mypage.se and both have expires set to session, if I change just mypage.se to have an expiration date, then it is not working, I need to be able to change both cookies, so both cookies gets the same expiration date.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson then set two different (`Response.AddHeader`) raw cookies as shown for `mypage.se` and `www.mypage.se` by removing the parts `expires=2038-01-01 10:00; `

Comment: OK, if I set this: Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "googtrans=/sv/en; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2038 12:00:00; domain=www.mypage.se; path=/" then the cookie domain becomes ".www.mypage.se" and not "www.mypage.se", it adds a dot before the "www" and thats is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this behavior with ASP because it is a function of the browser.

Cookies get stored/transmitted that way by the browser because the cookies are communicated over HTTP in the headers.  The slashes are encoded according to the URLEncoding schema.